# AngularJS: console.log does not display anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, console.log

I wrote a controller for login page. Here is my controller:

```
var authApp = angular.module('loginApp', [])

authApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'loginFactory', function($scope, $location, loginFactory){
    $scope.authenticate = function() {
        loginFactory.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.$statusText);
        }, function errorCallBack(response) {
            console.log(response.$statusText);
        });
    }

}]);
```

My service:

```
authApp.factory("loginFactory", function ($http) {
    return{
        login: function(username, password) {
            var data = "username="+username+"&password="+password+"&submit=Login";
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
                data: data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
            });  
        }
```

When I debug the code, authentication seems successful and it did get into `then` function. However nothing displays in console. And I got a warning(?) saying undefined for the line `console.log(response.$statusText);`. It is not an error since it is not red. Why doesn't it print out anything?

Comment: `console.log` must have displayed the result of `response.$statusText` as `undefined..`

Comment: @Rayon It is a post request, how could the response be undefined?

Comment: When you get something like this do `console.log(response);` so you can see everything in the object.

Comment: Every request will `respond` buddy! `response` object may not have the `$statusText` key..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `response.statusText` not `response.$statusText`. The documentation for AngularJS $http requests lists statusText as one of the properties of the response object - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: In the documentation for AngularJS http requests it lists statusText as one of the properties for response

Comment: Ooh yes! I was reading it as a response object from `server`.. You might want to add [__reference__](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)